# Integrating positive function on interval from -1 to 1 but result is negative

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following function:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac1 {x^4} dx$$

and my result seems to be:

$$\frac {-2}3$$

Why is my result negative? My function is always positive, does it have to do with the fact that since the interval extends from -1 to 1 but the function doesn't go there that it somehow drastically affects the total integral?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Note that $\frac{1}{x^4}$ is not defined at $x = 0$. Edit: On rereading your question, I believe you already knew this with your statement "the function doesn't go there".

Comment: The integrand is not defined at zero.

Comment: There is a fatal discontinuity at $0$, so the FTC doesn't apply.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$\dfrac1{x^4}$
is not defined at
$x=0$,
one definition of
$\int_{-1}^1 \frac1 {x^4} dx
$
is
$\lim_{c \to 0^+} (\int_{-1}^{-c} \frac1 {x^4} dx+\int_{c}^1 \frac1 {x^4} dx)
$.

We have
$\int \dfrac{dx}{x^4}
=\int x^{-4} dx
=\dfrac{x^{-3}}{-3}
=-\dfrac{1}{3x^3}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{-1}^{-c} \frac1 {x^4} dx
&=-\dfrac{1}{3x^3}|_{-1}^{-c}\\
&=-(\dfrac{1}{3(-c)^3}-\dfrac{1}{3(-1)^3})\\
&=-(-\dfrac{1}{3c^3}+\dfrac{1}{3})\\
&=\dfrac{1}{3c^3}-\dfrac{1}{3}\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
\int_{c}^{1} \frac1 {x^4} dx
&=-\dfrac{1}{3x^3}|_{c}^{1}\\
&=-(\dfrac{1}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3c^3})\\
&=\dfrac{1}{3c^3}-\dfrac{1}{3}\\
\end{array}
$

Adding these we get
$\dfrac{2}{3c^3}-\dfrac{2}{3}
$,
and the
$\dfrac{2}{3c^3}
$
overwhelms the
$-\dfrac{2}{3}
$.

Comment: Why must the upper bound for the first integral be $-c$? Can't it be $c$ as well?

Comment: A good answer. One small thing to note is that as $\frac{1}{x^4}$ is an even function, once you got the value of the first partial integral, you would know it's the exact same as the second partial integral.

Comment: The interval of integration can't include zero because $1/x^4$ is not defined there.